# How to query datetime based on date in c#

Tags: c#, ms-access, jet, dd

I have an MS-Access database with a DateTime column.
ex: `03/08/2009 12:00:00 AM`.

I want query based on date like:

```
select * from tablename where date='03/08/2009'
```

I want display data as `03/08/2009 12:00:00 AM`.

How would I write this query in C#?
Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some sample code using C# in a console app to access an Access DB. You can adapt this code to windows or ASP.NET if needed.

```
/* Replace with the path to your Access database */
string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\mydatabase.mdb;User Id=admin;Password=;";

try
{
using(OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString)
{
   conn.Open();       
   string myQuery = "Select * FROM tableName WHERE date='03/02/2009'";       
   OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(myQuery, conn);
   using(OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
   {
      //iterate through the reader here
      while(reader.Read())
      {
         //or reader[columnName] for each column name
         Console.WriteLine("Fied1 =" + reader[0]); 
      }
   }
}

}
catch (Exception e)
{
   Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The question is not programming language, but the query to mdb access. Access requires the word `DateValue` before you enter a date:

```
string myQuery = "Select * FROM tableName WHERE date= DateValue ('03/02/2009')";
```